# CCMenuitem not working properly after pushing the scene for the second time

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, ccmenuitem, ccmenu

I have a menuScene which has a play button. 
I have declared gameScene as a property in menuScene

```
    @property(nonatomic, strong) id gameScene;
```

and now allocating the gameScene in init method of menuScene as below.

```
    self.gameScene = [GameScene scene];
```

When the user presses the play button I am pushing the gameScene, as shown below

```
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pushScene:self.gameScene];
```

Now when I press the pause button in the gameScene, am pausing the game and showing the options menu which has resume and menu buttons.

```
    -(void)pauseButtonClicked {
       [CCDirector sharedDirector] pause];
       /*code to display options menu*/
    }
```

I am popping to the menuScene on click of menu button,

```
       - (void)menuButtonClicked {
          [self removeChild:pauseLayer cleanup:YES];
          [[CCDirector sharedDirector] resume];
          [[CCDirector sharedDirector] popScene];
       }
```

Now if I press play button again as I have declared gameScene as a property,  I am pushing the same gameScene to show the current state of the game, from now pause button is not detecting touches in the gameScene..

Comment: Check that the popped scene properly deallocs. If you override onEnter and other on* methods make sure to call [super onEnter] etc.